# Django REST Framework Customized Json Data Format

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I, started using **[Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)** few days ago, it's a wonderful framework, but I can't find info about this: 
I serialized my model "Deposito" and I get data in json format succesfully, but I want add some fields like total (total records).

Thanks for your help.

Data obtained with serializers.ModelSerializer

```
[{
    "id": 78,
    "Numero": "2014051100001",
    "Monto": "100.00",
    "Ingreso": "2014-08-13T22:30:00Z",
    "Entregado": true
},
{
    "id": 533,
    "Numero": "2014051100221",
    "Monto": "200.00",
    "Ingreso": "2014-08-22T14:45:00Z",
    "Entregado": true
}]
```

Data I want to get

```
{
    "rows": 
    [{
        "id": 78,
        "Numero": "2014051100001",
        "Monto": "100.00",
        "Ingreso": "2014-08-13T22:30:00Z",
        "Entregado": true
    },
    {
        "id": 533,
        "Numero": "2014051100221",
        "Monto": "200.00",
        "Ingreso": "2014-08-22T14:45:00Z",
        "Entregado": true
    }]
    "total": 2
}
```

Here is my code

```
# serializer.py
class DepositosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Deposito
        fields = ('id', 'Numero', 'Monto', 'Ingreso', 'Entregado')


#views.py
def DepositoByClient(request, cliente):
    """
    List Deposito by Cliente.
    """
    try:
        deposito = Deposito.objects.filter(Cliente=cliente, Entregado = True).order_by('Numero')
    except Deposito.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = DepositosSerializer(deposito)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's about just adding the total value to the data before returning the response?

```
#views.py
def DepositoByClient(request, cliente):
    """
    List Deposito by Cliente.
    """
    try:
        deposito = Deposito.objects.filter(Cliente=cliente, Entregado = True).order_by('Numero')
    except Deposito.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = DepositosSerializer(deposito)
        rows = serializer.data
        total =  # Whatever you want here ...
        return JSONResponse(dict(rows=rows, total=total))
```